# Excel organization

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have made a sample version of what I would like.

This form is ever repeating and the amounts values in the middle rows vary at all times. I would like to know if you know of a way to make the far right column check if all of the middle columns are approved, and from there will automatically show rejected if one or more are rejected, and approved if they are all approved.

This has to be repeatable and expandable as this is a file with hundreds of examples like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using just a formula, without any VBA.

I have set up a worksheet as follows:

[image: Workbook Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `N1` and `N20`:

```dart
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("Rejected",INDEX(G:G,ROW()):INDEX(G:G,IFERROR(MATCH("*",INDEX(L:L,ROW()+1):INDEX(L:L,ROWS(L:L)),0)+ROW()-1,MATCH("",G:G,-1))),0)),"Rejected","Approved")
```

I have used `L:L` in the formula, as I don't know the precise details of your worksheet. For the formula to work correctly, replace `L:L` with any text-only merged-cells column that doesn't contain any blanks.

Unfortunately as the merged cells are of different sizes, you can't fill the formula down. Also, you can only copy-paste the formula into merged cells of the same size.

The easiest way to enter the formula in the right most column is to use either of these key press sequences:

- <kbd>F2</kbd>  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

or

- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You could even record a macro to speed things up.

---

The prettified formula is as follows:

```dart
=
IF(
  ISNUMBER(
    MATCH(
      "Rejected",
      INDEX(G:G,ROW())
      :INDEX(G:G,
        IFERROR(
          MATCH("*",INDEX(L:L,ROW()+1):INDEX(L:L,ROWS(L:L)),0)+ROW()-1,
          MATCH("",G:G,-1)
        )
      ),
      0
    )
  ),
  "Rejected",
  "Approved"
)
```

**Notes:**

- The prettified formula actually works if entered.
- The brackets around `(G:G)` in the prettified version are required to force the `G:G` to remain on its own line.

---

**EDIT:**

If you wish to increase the list of status value from just `Rejected` and `Approved`, to `Rejected`, `Void`, `Pending` and `Approved`, you could just nest the `IF()` functions in the formula like so:

```dart
=
IF(
  ISNUMBER(
    MATCH(
      "Rejected",
      INDEX(G:G,ROW())
      :INDEX(G:G,
        IFERROR(
          MATCH("*",INDEX(L:L,ROW()+1):INDEX(L:L,ROWS(L:L)),0)+ROW()-1,
          MATCH("",G:G,-1)
        )
      ),
      0
    )
  ),
  "Rejected",
IF(
  ISNUMBER(
    MATCH(
      "Pending",
      INDEX(G:G,ROW())
      :INDEX(G:G,
        IFERROR(
          MATCH("*",INDEX(L:L,ROW()+1):INDEX(L:L,ROWS(L:L)),0)+ROW()-1,
          MATCH("",G:G,-1)
        )
      ),
      0
    )
  ),
  "Pending",
IF(
  ISNUMBER(
    MATCH(
      "Void",
      INDEX(G:G,ROW())
      :INDEX(G:G,
        IFERROR(
          MATCH("*",INDEX(L:L,ROW()+1):INDEX(L:L,ROWS(L:L)),0)+ROW()-1,
          MATCH("",G:G,-1)
        )
      ),
      0
    )
  ),
  "Void",
  "Approved"
)
)
)
```

A much better solution would be to use a formula that works with arrays:

```dart
=
CHOOSE(
  SMALL(
    IF(
      ISERROR(
        MATCH(
          {"Rejected","Void","Pending","Approved"},
          INDEX(G:G,ROW())
          :INDEX(G:G,
            IFERROR(
              MATCH("*",INDEX(L:L,ROW()+1):INDEX(L:L,ROWS(L:L)),0)+ROW()-1,
              MATCH("",G:G,-1)
            )
          ),
          0
        )
      ),
      FALSE,
      {1,2,3,4}
    ),
    1
  ),
  "Rejected","Void","Pending","Approved"
)
```

If you prefer the flattened version of the formula, here it is:

```dart
=CHOOSE(SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH({"Rejected","Void","Pending","Approved"},INDEX(G:G,ROW()):INDEX(G:G,IFERROR(MATCH("*",INDEX(L:L,ROW()+1):INDEX(L:L,ROWS(L:L)),0)+ROW()-1,MATCH("",G:G,-1))),0)),FALSE,{1,2,3,4}),1),"Rejected","Void","Pending","Approved")
```

This last version of the formula is easily extendable to more (or less) values by simply adjusting the two constant arrays and the list of values on the second last row.

Note that the exact order of the values determines which value is returned if more than one value type exists in the appropriate range. The highest priority value is the one on the left.

Comment: Ok thank you so much that is what I was looking for, although I have another question, if i were using "Void, Approved, Pending and Rejected" then how would I set it up to have more than just the two pending and rejected?

Comment: @P.Lou I've updated the answer with two new versions of the formula that cater for any number of status values. (I've also refactored the original formula to allow one of the new versions to be more easily created.)